# Rundeck ldap connection ends in NullPointerException

Tags: active-directory, ldap, rundeck

I'm currently in the process of migrating rundeck `v2.11.3` to `v3.4.0` (in a docker container), with my approach of setting up a fresh installation and moving all contents later. At the moment, I fail at setting up the LDAP connection (supplied by Active Directory running on a MS Windows Server 2016). I'm using the container `rundeck/rundeck:3.4.0` from DockerHub here, my `jaas-loginmodule.conf` looks like this:

```
rundeck {
    com.dtolabs.rundeck.jetty.jaas.JettyCombinedLdapLoginModule sufficient
        debug="true"
        contextFactory="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"
        providerUrl="ldap://10.16.0.4:389"
        bindDn="CN=devldap,CN=Users,DC=mycompany,DC=de"
bindPassword="xxx"
        authenticationMethod="simple"
        forceBindingLogin="true"
        forceBindingLoginUseRootContextForRoles="true"
        userBaseDn="dc=mycompany,dc=de"
        userRdnAttribute="userPrincipalName"
        userIdAttribute="userPrincipalName"
        userPasswordAttribute="unicodePwd"
        userObjectClass="user"
        roleBaseDn="ou=dev,ou=adgroups,dc=mycompany,dc=de"
        roleNameAttribute="cn"
        roleMemberAttribute="member"
        roleObjectClass="group"
        rolePrefix=""
        cacheDurationMillis="600000"
        reportStatistics="true"

    ;

    org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.spi.PropertyFileLoginModule required
        debug="true"
        file="/home/rundeck/server/config/realm.properties";


};
```

When trying to login using a ldap user, I get the following error stack:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.getNextBatch(AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.java:130)
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.nextAux(AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.java:258)
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.nextImpl(AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.java:249)
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.next(AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.java:203)
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.nextElement(AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.java:106)
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.nextElement(AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.java:40)
        at com.dtolabs.rundeck.jetty.jaas.JettyCachingLdapLoginModule.findUser(JettyCachingLdapLoginModule.java:905)
        at com.dtolabs.rundeck.jetty.jaas.JettyCachingLdapLoginModule.bindingLogin(JettyCachingLdapLoginModule.java:833)
        at com.dtolabs.rundeck.jetty.jaas.JettyCachingLdapLoginModule.authenticate(JettyCachingLdapLoginModule.java:738)
        at com.dtolabs.rundeck.jetty.jaas.JettyCombinedLdapLoginModule.login(JettyCombinedLdapLoginModule.java:161)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:726)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:665)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:663)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:663)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:574)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.jaas.AbstractJaasAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractJaasAuthenticationProvider.java:180)
        at org.rundeck.security.RundeckJaasAuthenticationProvider.super$2$authenticate(RundeckJaasAuthenticationProvider.groovy)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:144)
        at org.rundeck.security.RundeckJaasAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(RundeckJaasAuthenticationProvider.groovy:39)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:175)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.GrailsUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(GrailsUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.groovy:53)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:64)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:97)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:602)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1435)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1350)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:279)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:383)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:882)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1036)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[2021-07-21T07:36:54,544] INFO  web.requests "GET /user/error" 172.17.0.1 http  form 2 ? [] (Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.164 Safari/537.36)
```

I wonder, if there's any way to actually debug the connection and see, if it's some configuration error (the configuration above is taken from the existing instance of rundeck, which works fine) or might be some error in the rundeck application.

Comment: Hi! I tested the 3.4.1 multiauth config against an AD server and checking your config I see some differences (the first line of AD config calls another module, also check the userRdnAttributte and userIdAttribute values check the basic example here https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/authentication.html#ldap and finally make sure to launch Rundeck using OpenJDK 11). My config (jaas-multiauth.conf): https://pastebin.com/EExw5CZE and how I launch rundeck: https://pastebin.com/7gL4tk8T

Comment: Thanks for supplying this comment. Basically switching `RUNDECK_JAAS_LDAP_USERRDNATTRIBUTE` and `RUNDECK_JAAS_LDAP_USERIDATTRIBUTE` to sAMAccountName fixed the issue. In the docker container everything is prepared for doing "multiauth", being filled through environment parameters. Can you please supply your configuration as answer?

Comment: Good news then! Posted as answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some differences with [example](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/authentication.html#active-directory) AD config (the first line of AD config calls another module, also check the `userRdnAttributte` and `userIdAttribute` values, finally, make sure to launch Rundeck using OpenJDK 11).

Anyway, I tested successfully with the following multiauth config:

```
multiauth {
  com.dtolabs.rundeck.jetty.jaas.JettyCachingLdapLoginModule sufficient
      debug="true"
      contextFactory="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"
      providerUrl="ldap://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:389"
      bindDn="admin@example.local"
      bindPassword="password"
      authenticationMethod="simple"
      forceBindingLogin="true"
      userBaseDn="OU=Users,OU=company,DC=example,DC=local"
      userRdnAttribute="sAMAccountName"
      userIdAttribute="sAMAccountName"
      userPasswordAttribute="unicodePwd"
      userObjectClass="user"
      roleBaseDn="OU=Roles,OU=company,DC=example,DC=local"
      roleNameAttribute="cn"
      roleMemberAttribute="member"
      roleObjectClass="group"
      cacheDurationMillis="300000"
      //supplementalRoles="admin"
      reportStatistics="true";
 
  org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.spi.PropertyFileLoginModule required
    debug="true"
    file="/home/user/rundeck/server/config/realm.properties";
};
```

And launching rundeck in this way:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
 
# rundeck information
version=rundeck-3.4.1-20210715.war
min=1024m
max=2048m
 
# run
java -Xms$min -Xmx$max -Drundeck.jaaslogin=true -Dloginmodule.conf.name=jaas-multiauth.conf -Dloginmodule.name=multiauth -jar $version
```